# Next Letter in alphabet

Tags: python, string

I am stuck on how to make Z turn into A on the cs circles problem Next Letter

```
x =input()

x=x.upper()

x=chr(ord(x) + 1)

print(x)
```

how do i get z to turn into A?

Comment: Do you want z to A or a?

Comment: Since you are stuck this means you have tried something before. What have you tried, and what happened?

Comment: I need Z to turn into A

Comment: if x == "Z":
   print("A")

if x == "Z":
   print(ord(81))

if x == "Z":
   print(chr(65))

Comment: if x == "z": x="A"

Answer (score 9):

Using `chr` and `ord`:

```
def next_alpha(s):
    return chr((ord(s.upper())+1 - 65) % 26 + 65)

for s in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    print('%s --> %s' % (s, next_alpha(s)))

a --> B
b --> C
...
y --> Z
z --> A
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution to find the next alphabets of multiple alphabets.**

Example: 
**input** - abc 
**output** - bcd

**user_input = input("Enter your word: ")

lst = list(''.join(user_input.lower()))

lst1= []

str1=''
for i in range(len(lst)):**

```
x = ord(lst[i])  #ord() is used to convert char to ascii value
x=x+1
if x==123:
    x=97
    y= chr(x)       
    lst1.append(y)
    str1 =''.join(lst1)
else:
    y= chr(x)       #chr() is used to convert ascii to char value
    lst1.append(y)
    str1 =''.join(lst1)
```

**print(str1)**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
x = input()
x = x.upper()
order = ord(x)
if order ==90:
      order = 64
      x=chr(order + 1)
      print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to solve `Next Letter` Question.

```
charac = input()

if charac == "Z": # If Z encountered change to A
   print(chr(ord(charac)-25))

else:
   change = ord(charac) + 1
   print(chr(change))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract 25 from the `ord` value of 'Z' or 'z':

```
x = input('Enter Alphabet: ')
print(chr(ord(x)-25))
```

Output:

```
Enter Alphabet: z
a
```

Comment: Uh, Fails for `z`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, this code allows users to type in multiple letters:

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_letters
x = input()
x = list(x.lower())
for i,v in enumerate(x):
   x[i] = letters[letters.index(v) + 1]
print(''.join(x).upper())
```

Example output:

```
azd
BAE
```

If you don't need them to type in multiple letters, use:

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_letters
x = input()
x = x.lower()
x = letters[letters.index(x) + 1]
print(x.upper())
```

Example output:

```
z
A
```

Answer (score 0):

to increment the alphabet in lower case in clockwise

```
a = input("ENTER THE ALPHABET:")

inc=int(input("ENTER INCREMENT VALUE:"))

x = ord(a)

x=x+inc

if x>=123:

    x=x-122
    x=96+x
    print(chr(x))
else:

    print(chr(x))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use modular arithmetic. Try this:

```
    c = input().upper()
    n = chr(ord('A')+(ord(c)-ord('A')+1)%26)
    print(n)
```

Comment: This answer works just fine. The asker may be a new programmer so explaining the mod operator is likely to give a more thorough explanation of what you're doing.